# How to update a current file that has been already committed?

Tags: git, github, repository, commit

I have already committed my file to my git repository, and now I have edited my file and would like to replace or update my previous version. How can I go about it?

Comment: Update the file locally, commit it, and push.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another commit and push it to GitHub.